# Unable to write the file while using windowing for streaming data use to ":" in Windows

Tags: java, timestamp, apache-beam, apache-beam-io, windowing

I am encountering an issue when running my Java ApacheBeam code. The program throws an error when trying to create a file with a colon in the name on my Windows system, stating that the file name is invalid.

I understood that the error was due to my windowingTimestamp where it contains : in its timestame as a file name.

I stuck in converting my timestamp value, i dont want to have a basic default file name.

Actual file Name: output2020-12-12T15:00:10.000Z-2020-12-12T15:00:15.000Z-pane-0-last-00000-of-00001

Expected file Name: output2020-12-12T15.00.10.000Z-2020-12-12T15.00.15.000Z-pane-0-last-00000-of-00001

```
output.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Long>,String> (){

     @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c, BoundedWindow window){

        /*In Terminal Results
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "%s: %s %s", window.maxTimestamp(), c.element(). getKey(),c.element().getValue()));

         */
         c.output(String.format("%s %s %s",window.maxTimestamp(), Objects.requireNonNull(c.element()).getKey(), Objects.requireNonNull(c.element()).getValue()));

    }
})).apply(TextIO.write().to("src/main/resources/Sink/FixedWindow/output").withWindowedWrites().withNumShards(1));
```

Comment: Windows filenames can't contain ":", as it could be confused with drive letter or with file streams. For example `c:Temp` already could mean a file `c` with stream `Temp` (not in Java), or drive `c` and dir/file `Temp` depending on context.

Comment: You are absolutely right. But i need the solution for this

Comment: When you define a filename just use `.replace(':', 'x')`